# How to incorporate script to spike elastalert

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elastalert

I want to setup an alert to notify me when an spike occurs. My data is structured as such:

```
"_source": {
          "@timestamp": 2016-11-23T18:30:45.233Z,
          "invalid_request": 400,
          "total_request": 40000
        }
```

I want to setup an spike alert that send me email if invalid requests ratio has a spike over 20 minutes period, but the following rule yaml doesn't give me any hit.

```
# (Required)
# Rule name, must be unique
name: Invlid Count Spike

# (Required)
# Type of alert.
# (Required)
# Index to search, wildcard supported
index: logstash-*

# (Required one of _cur or _ref, spike specific)
# The minimum number of events that will trigger an alert
threshold_cur: 1
#threshold_ref: 5
# The size of the window used to determine average event frequency
# We use two sliding windows each of size timeframe
# To measure the 'reference' rate and the current rate
timeframe:
  minutes: 20

# (Required, spike specific)
# The spike rule matches when the current window contains spike_height times more
# events than the reference window
spike_height: 2

# (Required, spike specific)
# The direction of the spike
# 'up' matches only spikes, 'down' matches only troughs
# 'both' matches both spikes and troughs
spike_type: "both"

# (Required)
# A list of elasticsearch filters used for find events
# These filters are joined with AND and nested in a filtered query
# For more info: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/c
urrent/query-dsl.html
script_fields:
  invalid_ratio:
    script:
       doc['invalid_request'].value / doc['total_request'].value
filter:
- range:
    invalid_ratio:
      gt: 0

# (Required)
# The alert is use when a match is found
alert:
- "email"

# (required, email specific)
# a list of email addresses to send alerts to
email:
- "john.doe@email.com"
```

I know my email sending is working ok, because it sends out email if I just put a simple query (such as trigger when total_request is greater than 0), but it seems the script I put in is not working as I expected. Anyone familiar with elastalarm would be greatly helpful on the matter. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually tried this, but I think your ES filters are wrong, `script_fields` is not supported by Elastalert (as far as I know). And even if it did, you cannot reference `script_fields` inside your `range` filter anyway (not supported by ES).

You can try using a [`script` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html), though. Remove your `script_fields` section and replace the `filter` section with this:

```
filter:
- script:
    script:
      inline: doc['invalid_request'].value / doc['total_request'].value > threshold
      params:
        threshold: 0
```